# Solving code-forces "1A Theatre Square" in C

Tags: c, math, format-specifiers

novice programmer here trying to get better at C, so i began doing code problems on a website called codeforces. However i seem to be stuck, i have written code that appears to work in practice but the website does not accept it as right.

the problem :

Theatre Square in the capital city of Berland has a rectangular shape with the size n × m meters. On the occasion of the city's anniversary, a decision was taken to pave the Square with square granite flagstones. Each flagstone is of the size a × a. What is the least number of flagstones needed to pave the Square? It's allowed to cover the surface larger than the Theatre Square, but the Square has to be covered. It's not allowed to break the flagstones. The sides of flagstones should be parallel to the sides of the Square.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkXJs.png)

Source :

https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/1/A

I did have a hard time completely understanding the math behind the problem and used this source's answer from a user named "Joshua Pan" to better understand the problem

Source :

https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-solve-the-problem-Theatre-Square-on-Codeforces

This is my code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(void)
{
    double n,m,a;
    scanf("%lf %lf %lf", &n,&m,&a);
    printf("%1.lf\n", ceil(n/a)*ceil(m/a));

    return 0;
}
```

I compiled it using "gcc TheatreSquare.c -lm"

When given the sample input 6,6,4 my code produces the correct output 4, however the website does not accept this code as correct, i could be wrong but maybe im using format specifiers incorrectly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typical `double` (IEEE754 64-bit floating point) doesn't have enough accuracy for the problem.

For example, for input

```
999999999 999999999 1
```

Your program may give output

```
999999998000000000
```

While the actual answer is

```
999999998000000001
```

To avoid this, you shouldn't use floating point data type.

You can add `#include <inttypes.h>` and use 64-bit integer type `int64_t` for this calculation.

`"%" SCNd64` is for reading and `"%" PRId64` is for writing `int64_t`.

`cell(n/a)` on integers can be done by `(n + a - 1) / a`.

Comment: The original problem description specifies `a, n, m <= 10^9`, so 32-bit integers suffice.

Comment: @EOF It is true for input, but not for output because `(n/a) * (m/a)` can be more than `10^10`.

Comment: @MikeCAT Forgive me for asking but im still new to all this. <inttypes.h> is a library and int64_t is a data type from said library. But im still having a hard time understanding how to use SCNd64 & PRId64 correctly. I have looked online but its still unclear. scanf("%PRId64", &n,&a)?

Comment: It will be like `scanf("%" SCNd64, &n);`

Comment: @mrStap: `<inttypes.h>` is not a library. It is a header file. Header files are typically used to declare things. Fundamentally, they are just source code that contains information or the compiler. Sometimes they declare routines that are in libraries. But the actual routines are in different files (which must be included when *linking* your program). But `<stdint.h>` merely declares names for types and some macros to help use those types. So it is just a file of source code with no associated library.

Comment: @MikeCAT Hello, i tried it and it passed test 1 & 2 but failed test 3. Not sure why if your interest in looking at my work or solving this let me know. I wont bother you anymore than i already have. I appreciate all your help.

Comment: @EricPostpischil oh ok thanks for the clarification. I guess i need to look up what defines a library then. This sounds very complicated do you have any recommendations on where i could learn more? im planning to read the dragon book after i finish with my C studies.

Comment: @mrStap [My solution](https://codeforces.com/contest/1/submission/88668234) is accepted, so your implementation should be wrong.

Comment: @MikeCAT thank you very much for showing me what you did. I didn't do the if statement. Could you explain what the !=3 does?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this using integers.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned long n, m, a = 1;
    unsigned long na, ma, res = 0;
    
    scanf("%lu %lu %lu", &n, &m, &a);
    
    na = n/a;

    if (n%a != 0)
        na++;
    
    ma = m/a;

    if (m%a != 0)
        ma++;

    res = na * ma;

    printf("%lu", res);

    return 0;
}
```

This code will fail in the Codeforce platform, on the test 9 (see below). But if you compile it and run it locally with the same inputs, the result is correct.

```
> Test: #9, time: 15 ms., memory: 3608 KB, exit code: 0, checker exit code: 1, verdict: WRONG_ANSWER
> Input 1000000000 1000000000 1
> Output 2808348672 Answer 1000000000000000000
> Checker Log wrong answer 1st numbers differ - expected: '1000000000000000000', found: '2808348672'
```

**EDIT:**

The problem described above is due to the fact that I'm running a 64-bit machine and the online compiler is probably using 32-bit. The `unsigned long` variables overflow.

The following code will pass all the tests.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned long long n, m, a = 1;
    unsigned long long na, ma, res = 0;
    
    scanf("%llu %llu %llu", &n, &m, &a);
    
    na = n/a;

    if (n%a != 0)
        na++;
    
    ma = m/a;

    if (m%a != 0)
        ma++;

    res = na * ma;

    printf("%llu", res);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
import math

x,y,z=list(map(float, input().split()))  
print(math.ceil(x/z)*math.ceil(y/z))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below it will pass all the test cases we need to use long long for all variable declaration to get output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(){
    long long n,m,a,l,b;
    scanf("%lld%lld%lld",&n,&m,&a);
    l= n/a;
    if(n%a != 0)
    l++;
    b= m/a;
    if(m%a != 0)
    b++;
    printf("%lld",l*b);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for the above problem in CPP. We need a long long variable to store the value as we may have a very large value.

**GUIDANCE ABOUT THE QUESTION:**

As we are given the hint of edges so we have to cover them nicely. For a rectangle, we know that we have a length and height which is shown as n * m and the square is of a*a so we will try to cover the length first and decide its squares first
for that, we divide it by k, and then if any remainder exists we will add one more and the same for height.

**I hope it will help you**

**HERE IS THE CODE**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   long long n,m,k,l=0,o=0;
   cin>>n>>m>>k;
   
   l=n/k;
   if(n%k!=0)
   {
          l++;
   }
   
   o=m/k;
   
   if(m%k!=0)
   { 
         o++;
   }
   
   cout<<l*o;
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Theatre Square in the capital city of Berland has a rectangular shape with the size n × m meters. On the occasion of the city's anniversary, a decision was taken to pave the Square with square granite flagstones. Each flagstone is of the size a × a.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class theatre_square {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long a,b,c;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        a = s.nextLong();
        b = s.nextLong();
        c = s.nextLong();
        long result = 0;
        if(a>=c){
            if(a%c==0) 
            result = a/c;
            else
            result = a/c + 1; // some part is left
        }else{ // area of rectangle < area of square then 1 square is required
            result = 1;
        }
        if(b>=c){
            if(b%c==0)
            result *= b/c;
            else
            result *= b/c + 1;
        }
        System.out.println(result);

    }
}




 case 1 .  2 2 3 => 1
          length = 2 so 2 < 3 then only 1 square required <br>
          breadth = 2 so 2 < 3 then covered in previous square so output 1
          
              intial view 
               
              0 0
              0 0

             after adding 1 square ( r= remaining or left)
      
              1 1 r
              1 1 r
              r r r

case 2 .  6 6 4  => 4
          length = 2 so 6 > 4 then only 2 square required <br>
          breadth = 2 so 6 > 4 then 2 square required 
          
              intial view 
               
              0 0 0 0 0 0
              0 0 0 0 0 0
              0 0 0 0 0 0
              0 0 0 0 0 0
              0 0 0 0 0 0
              0 0 0 0 0 0


             after adding 4 square ( r= remaining or left)
      
              1 1 1 1 2 2 r r
              1 1 1 1 2 2 r r
              1 1 1 1 2 2 r r
              1 1 1 1 2 2 r r
              3 3 3 3 4 4 r r
              3 3 3 3 4 4 r r
              r r r r r r r r
              r r r r r r r r
```